# PWM In a stepper motor

Tags: pwm, stepper-motor

How can one drive a stepper motor and control its speed using PWM from a microcontroller, since the stepper motor has more than two wires?

I just want a confirmation because I'm still confused.

Comment: *Confirmation* means you need to *confirm a statement already made*; what do you want to confirm?

Comment: You need to learn how steppers work. They normally don't use PWM. Usually four windings are switched in sequence to pull to rotor around. There are millions of articles about stepper motors on the web.

Comment: Yet it's perfectly legal to use advanced pwm technics for microstepping.

Comment: @MarcusMüller When I researched the control of the stepper motor I found that It can be controlled by pwm, but so far I didnt find how the motor is controlled by pwm, so I wanted to know how can it be controlled using pwm since it has many wires, so what I wanna confirming is that: do u need many pwm to control the motor or u need one?

Answer (score 1):

If you use bbipolar stepper motor, it has two phases, so you drive it with two PWM signals at least. In more advanced aapplications- two PWM per phase, so four.  I wonder, if you know, where to connect this signals... I think, you should start with DRV8811, then you need one GPIO for direction and another one for step. No PWM rrequired.

Comment: Thanks I will study the DRV8811 so far I only studied uln2003.